# Hive Query - Pivot Table by First and Last Entry of Date

Tags: database, hive

To start here is some sample data

Sample Input

```
ID      Date                   Value
10      2012-06-01 00:01:45    20
10      2012-06-01 00:01:51    12
10      2012-06-01 00:01:56    21
10      2012-06-01 00:02:01    43
10      2012-06-01 00:02:06    12
17      2012-06-01 00:02:43    64
17      2012-06-01 00:02:47    53
17      2012-06-01 00:02:52    23
17      2012-06-01 00:02:58    45
17      2012-06-01 00:03:03    34
```

Desired Output

```
ID      Date
10      2012-06-01 00:01:45    2012-06-01 00:02:06    20    12
17      2012-06-01 00:02:43    2012-06-01 00:03:03    64    34
```

So I am looking to get the first and last date, and values for both into a single line. The ID value in my table will also have other entries at later dates, so I only want to get the first and last for a chain of entries. Each entry is 5 secs apart. If they are greater then that it is a new chain.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a MapReduce job to work on the csv files of my data instead of using hive.

I "mapped" based on ID. Then set a parameter where if data's were further then 2 hours I separated them.

In the end it was easily to hack the MapReduce code then ponder hive queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just beginning the search process on this but it looks like `LATERAL VIEW` and `EXPLODE` coupled with maybe a user defined function or two are your friend.

Comment: ended up not doing this in HIve, and instead wrote my own MR job.